# How can preg_replace @<a>@</a> to <a>@</a>?

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML code like this:

```
@<a href="user_link">@user_name</a>
```

How can remove the first @ by using preg_match?

I just want the preg_replace code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

match `@` which came before `<a` tag. try following regular expression

```
preg_replace("/@(<a)/", "$1", '@<a href="user_link">@user_name</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. preg_match — Perform a regular expression match
2. preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace

So I guess you really need the second:

```
preg_replace('/^@/', '', '@<a href="user_link">@user_name</a>');
```

Comment: Thank you and yes i mean preg_replace but with your code it's working for first element only example:
preg_replace('/^@/', '', '@<a href="user_link">@user_name</a> @<a href="user_link">@user_name</a>');

it will print:
@user_name @@user_name
,,,, I need it to search for all the text not only first element.

Comment: preg_replace('/@(<a)/','$1','@<a href="user_link">@user_name</a> @<a href="user_link">@user_name</a>');